# Probability using baye's theorem and without using baye's theorem - example

Tags: probability

> There are three boxes. First box has 2 green and 4 black balls. Second box has 1 green and 2
>   black balls. Third box contains 5 green and 4 black balls.
>
> probability of selecting first box is 1/4 . Probability of selecting
>   second box is 1/2. Probability of selecting third box is 1/4.
>
> Suppose a green ball is selected.  What is the probability that it was
>   from first box

My approach

> probability of green ball given first box is selected =1/3
>
> using baye's theorem, probablity of first box given green ball given
>   is selected
>
> =(1/3*1/4)/(1/4*1/3+1/2*1/3+1/4*5/9)=0.21

(1) Is my approach right?

(2) Please provide alternative approaches also without using baye's theorem(like using permutations/combinations, conditional probability etc)

Thanks

Comment: Please change the title. It has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: sorry, happened by oversight. changed the title.

Comment: was the downvote due to the title? if so, please reconsider.

Comment: Your setup is right. I think the fraction simplifies to $3/14$. Your $0.21$ is presumably a calculator approximation to that. The conditional probability calculation is the same, just goes back to basics a little more. You could also explain the calculation using a tree diagram. Much more casually (too casually?) you could imagine doing the experiment $900$ times and give rough counts of outcomes.

Comment: @André Nicolas thanks a lot. Thanks to this site, I am now quite familiar with baye's theorem and I am much ahead in my syllabus. I will go throgh the basics and try solving it without this theorem. thanks.

Comment: @Kiran: I am not fond of the Bayes' Theorem approach, and prefer going back to the *definition* of conditional probability. My only reason is that over the years I have observed that people who use the Bayes formalism end up with the wrong answer more often than people who use the definition of conditional probability.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, one doubt here. In this question, total probability of selecting any one box is 1/4+1/2+1/4=1. Suppose the total was less than one. Still, can we use the same approach?

Comment: It would be an unusual problem. Let the probabilities for the boxes be $a$, $b$, $c$, with sum less than $1$ (with positive probability we decide not to bother playing with boxes). We got a green ball, so presumably we decided to play. The relevant probabilities are then $\frac{a}{a+b+c}$, and so on, which add up to $1$.

Comment: @ André Nicolas, thanks. I am creating a new problem to prove this point for clarification. thanks for helping.

Comment: @André Nicolas, could you please help me for answering http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1865885/probability-using-bayes-theorem-and-without-using-bayes-theorem-part-2 so that this will be very clear. thanks