# Probability using bayes' theorem and without using bayes' theorem - part 2

Tags: probability

Extension to the [problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1865796/probability-using-bayes-theorem-and-without-using-bayes-theorem-example)

> There are three boxes. First box has 2 green and 4 black balls. Second
>   box has 1 green and 2 black balls. Third box contains 5 green and 4
>   black balls.
>
> probability of selecting first box is 1/3 . Probability of selecting
>   second box is 1/6. Probability of selecting third box is 1/3.
>
> Suppose a green ball is selected. What is the probability that it was
>   from first box

**Approach 1**

If I go with the same method of the previous problem cited, using baye's theorem, answer will be

=(1/3*1/3)/(1/3*1/3+1/6*1/3+1/3*5/9)=0.31

However, here the total probability is less than 1
(i.e., 1/3+1/6+1/3 < 1)

Therefore, as pointed by @André Nicolas for the previous problem, this approach will not be correct(as the total probability is less than 1).  How to solve this problem then? please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because a green ball was selected, we will assume that we chose one of the boxes.

**Given** that we chose one of the boxes, the a priori probability we chose Box A is $\frac{1/3}{1/3+1/6+1/3}$, that is, $\frac{2}{5}$. The corresponding probabilities for Box B and Box C are $\frac{1}{5}$ and $\frac{2}{5}$.

Now do the usual sort of conditional probability / Bayes' Theorem calculation.

*Remark:* Since the *relative weights* are preserved, we would get the same answer for conditional probability it came from the first box by doing the usual calculation with the probabilities $\frac{1}{3}$, $\frac{1}{6}$, and $\frac{1}{3}$. However, I think one might lose control over the logic of the calculation, so the above preliminary rescaling is useful.

However, we can alternately invent a fourth box $D$ with $0$ green, and say $1$ purple,  and assign it the remaining probability $\frac{1}{6}$. Then the calculation just involves adding a term $(1/6)(0)$ to the denominator.

Comment: but using baye's theorem will give the answer as  (1/3*1/3)/(1/3*1/3+1/6*1/3+1/3*5/9) = 6/19. please see

Comment: oh I got the point. Instead of 1/3, 1/6, 1/3, we have to use probabilities 2/5, 1/5 and 2/5 and then use baye's theorem, am i right? but we did so because the total probability was less than 1?

Comment: @Kiran: Using the Theorem with the "right" probabilities will give $\frac{(2/5)(1/3)}{(2/5)(1/3)+(1/5)(1/3)+(2/5)(5/9)}$, which is $6/19$. (I pointed out in a comment that using rescaled probabilities will give the same answer as using original probabilities).

Comment: as you rightly said, both are giving same answer:  (1/3*2/5)/(2/5*1/3+1/5*1/3+2/5*5/9) =6/19;   (1/3*1/3)/(1/3*1/3+1/6*1/3+1/3*5/9) is also 6/19

Comment: I have found an interesting fact about this. if we do in this way,  say if we select a green ball, probability that it was from first box is 6/19, probability that it was from second box is 3/19 and probability that it was from third box is 10/19.  6/19+3/19+10/19=1. It means, it a green ball is selected, it is from one of the three boxes. Since the total probability of selecting any of these three boxes is less than 1, do you see a contradiction?

Comment: If there is no other way to get a green, there is no contradiction. I built that assumption into my rescaling procedure so that all assumptions would be clear.

Comment: this is so exciting and interesting, thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @Kiran:  You are welcome. Conditional probability can be treacherous, the intuition does not necessarily give correct results. That is why it is important to set up things clearly. We want to find $\Pr(A\mid B)$. Before setting the machinery lose on this, one needs to carefully identify $A$ and $B$. After that is done, the rest is often pretty mechanical.